# MySQL install on OSX, I want to start again, is it safe to delete all mysql folders?

Tags: mysql, macos, installation

I want to start again with attempting to install MySQL on OSX, I typed this to find all folders find / -name mysql.  Is it safe just to delete all of the folders that I found?

```
/opt/local/include/mysql5/mysql
/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql
/opt/local/lib/mysql5/mysql
/opt/local/share/mysql5/mysql
/opt/local/var/db/mysql5/mysql
/opt/local/var/macports/software/mysql5/5.1.40_0/opt/local/include/mysql5/mysql
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about any of the data that might be in there, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to find and destroy `my.ini` which should be in `/etc/` or some configuration directory.